# Count values in PHP array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, object

This may be a basic question but I am struggling with a way to count values without doing multiple `foreach` loops.  I have this array of objects (partial list included):

```
array(51) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#971 (4) {
    ["hole"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["club"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["shot_type"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["shot_loc"]=>
    string(1) "6"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#970 (4) {
    ["hole"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["club"]=>
    string(2) "16"
    ["shot_type"]=>
    string(1) "8"
    ["shot_loc"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#969 (4) {
    ["hole"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["club"]=>
    string(2) "19"
    ["shot_type"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["shot_loc"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [3]=>
  object(stdClass)#968 (4) {
    ["hole"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["club"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["shot_type"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["shot_loc"]=>
    string(1) "6"
  }
  [4]=>
  object(stdClass)#967 (4) {
    ["hole"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["club"]=>
    string(2) "15"
    ["shot_type"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["shot_loc"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
```

The number of objects in the list vary but each object will have the `key=>values` as shown.  What I would like to return is an array with count of each of the values of "hole".  Something like this:

```
`array(18) {
  [1]=> 4
  [2]=> 5
  [3]=> 6`
```

and so on where the key is each of the values of "hole" and the new array value is the count.

I have attempted forms of `count`, `count(get_object_vars($))`, and others but all examples I find are counting the objects. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `array_key_exists()` Then count the values.

Comment: by that you mean your trying to count all the elements inside each object? and why not use a `foreach`? whats wrong with it anyway

Comment: @aldrin, thanks for the tip.  But I know the key = "hole" will exist in each object but how do I get to finding the value and counting the number of times each value occurs?

Comment: @Ghost.  Sorry if i was not clear. No, I am trying to count the number of times the values for "hole"=> 1, 2, 3, 4.....18 occur in the array without doing 18 loops.

Comment: the question is not clear i think. Can you simple say what you want?

Comment: @oldnewbe oh okay so thats what it is (its an 18 standard hole or something), man i'm too dumb know anything about golf

Comment: you want to get count of occurencies for hole or you want to count value of the hole? Or hole can be array of values and you want to count the values of the hole?

Comment: Ghost - haha, yes golf app. it's your php skills I need.  @dare sorry for the confusion, each object in the array will have a key=>value of "hole"=>1 or "hole"=>2 and so on through maybe 18.  I want to count the number of times each hole value appears and return an array like i showed above.

Comment: @oldnewbe i don't know if there is such single incantation array function that does this all, but the simplest way that i could think of is just to use a simple `foreach`, use the hole value as key, then increment the value all the way, shouldn't cost that many lines too, check out david's answer below

Comment: @ghost.  thanks.  David below hit it on the sweet spot.  I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing, but this should do the trick for you:

```
$holes = [];
foreach ($array as $object) {
    if (isset($object->hole)) {
        $hole = $object->hole;
        if (!isset($holes[$hole])) {
            $holes[$hole] = 0;
        }
        $holes[$hole]++;
    }
}
```

I tested it using this:

```
$object1 = (object)['hole'=>'2'];
$object2 = (object)['hole'=>'3'];
$object3 = (object)['hole'=>'1'];
$object4 = (object)['hole'=>'3'];

$array = [$object1,$object2,$object3,$object4];

$holes = [];
foreach ($array as $object) {
    if (isset($object->hole)) {
        $hole = $object->hole;
        if (!isset($holes[$hole])) {
            $holes[$hole] = 0;
        }
        $holes[$hole]++;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($holes);
```

---

Prints

```
Array
(
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 2
    [1] => 1
)
```

Comment: Genius...or should i say hole in one...  Thanks works like a charm.

Comment: maybe $holes[$hole]++ in else or return? eg. if not isset so set to 0 and dont do anything more

Comment: Glad to have helped. Mastering object and array manipulation inside and out will get you places!

Comment: @DavidWyly if you have simple objects and you don't like objects you can retype to array by (array) $object and work with as array on vice versa using (object)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want an array of 18 (?) elements returned with the count of number of occurences of each hole.

```
$new_array = array_reduce($your_array, function ($carry, $item) {
  if (property_exists($item, "hole") && array_key_exists($item->hole - 1, $carry)) {
    $carry[$item->hole - 1]++;
  }
  return $carry;
}, array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0));
```

Comment: I tried this but kept getting an error on the `array_key_exists` looking for an array name as the second item.  tried different versions of your suggestion but did not have success. Thanks for the help, though.

Comment: Oops, I had the parameters backwards for array_key_exists, they are the reverse order to property_exists for a Real Good Reason I'm sure.  Fixed.

Comment: Thanks Jame.  I'll try it out.